# How would you translate “dragon's archers” into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm participating in the creation of an archery club, and we want name it *dragon's archers* in Latin. The Google Translate result *draco 
sagittariis* doesn't convince me. I think the declination is not correct. I bet for *sagittarii draconis*.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean Dragon's Archers/Archers of the Dragon it would be "Dracōnis sagittāriī"

Or if you mean Dragons' Archers/Archers of the Dragons it would be "Dracōnum sagittāriī".

As an alternative, it could be just "Dracōnēs sagittāriī", dragon-archers or archer-dragons.

Note: both terms of any of those three sentences may be used in whichever order you like.

Comment: Yes, I mean *dragon's archers*. I've edited the question.

Comment: About the order, it's preferable to use NOM + GEN (*Sagittāriī dracōnis*)?

Comment: You may use whichever you want :)

Comment: Is it the answer you were looking for?